# Does a video fragment request on loop return all the content each time?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, video, resources

I have a website which is using a media fragment on a html5 video. This video is set to autoplay and loop (not my choice). I'm concerned about the performance impact of this.

```
<video autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://example.com/video.mp4#t=10,20">
</video>
```

When viewing the network panel in chrome it seems to make a new resource for each loop of the video and the requests and MB transferred keeps going up... forever :(

Anyone know the performance impact of this and whether is actually downloading the fragment of video each time. Would this bypass the cache as it's a new resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have the disable cache setting ticked in the network tab. If you disable this then it only loads the video once, rather than reloading at the end of each loop.

I thought the same thing recently when doing some optimization.

Comment: Good spot. 

I guess this would still be an issue if the user has caching turned off for some reason.